# Is there a way to access azure blob storage using SAS(shared access signatures) URI in java/python code

Tags: azure, blob

I have an Azure SAS URI. I need to upload file in the same. Can I access it using java code. I can only find example using the key and the SAS(shared access signatures) URI.

[image: Sample SAS URI]

Comment: `I can only find example using the key and the SAS(shared access signatures) URI.`...Not sure what exactly you're looking for. You already found sample using SAS URI? In any case, asking for code samples is off topic here.

Comment: I looking for the class or function that can allow me to access SAS URI in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Azure Storage SDK for java`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java#upload-blobs-to-a-container) . To upload a file, you just need to use the class CloudBlockBlob which should look like,

```
URL url = new URL("yourSASUrl");
try
{
    CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(url)
    File source = new File(filePath);
    blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
}
```